# ProGuard deobfuscation in Sentry with pure Java

Tags: java, gradle, proguard, sentry

#### Context

We are looking into obfuscating our Java application with **ProGuard**, however we also use **Sentry** to detect issues, especially in production clients.

I have created a simple **Gradle** pipeline to include **Sentry** into a sandbox project, compile it, run it, build a JAR and then obfuscate said JAR.

As expected **Sentry** receives logs from obfuscated classes, so anything coming from my JAR is unreadable. Errors in external dependencies still read fine. Example-stacktrace:

```
a.e in actionPerformed
javax.swing.AbstractButton in fireActionPerformed
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler in actionPerformed
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel in fireActionPerformed
```

Notice the `a.e in actionPerformed` where `a.e` is my class and `actionPerformed` derives from **Swing**, *i.e.* a dependency.

#### Question

I know **Sentry** is able to deobfuscate code that was obfuscated with **ProGuard** if a mapping is provided. However the documentation on how to do this refers exclusively to Android and I was unable to get it to work:

https://docs.sentry.io/cli/dif/proguard/

As of right now I have searched through their documentation and Github repo, unable to find what I am looking for. Maybe I have missed it somewhere?

Available to me are:

- My `build.gradle`, which is a possible entry point to achieve this.
- `proguard_config.pro`, the configuration of **ProGuard**, defining the obfuscation process.
- `sentry.properties` file, where DSN is set.
- `proguard_mapping` file, which I assume needs to be provided to the server running **Sentry**.

How do I go about solving this? If all else fails our solution is going to be to lessen the degree of obfuscation until the messages provided to **Sentry** become readable enough to be useful to us. However the optimal solution is fully obfuscating the JAR and then deobfuscating classes and methods directly in **Sentry**.

So far I have spent a lot of time learning **Gradle** from zero and then loading **ProGuard** and **Sentry** with my **Gradle** pipeline. As the stacktrace shows this is already working, but I am runnung against a wall with the mapping. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I believe the `sentry-cli` only handles Android applications currently. You'd have to POST the mappings to Sentry manually and then associate them with a specific version. Or create a PR for `sentry-cli`: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/blob/master/src/commands/upload_proguard.rs

Comment: Thank you, will look into that.

Comment: @Mär did you get anywhere? I have the same issue.

Comment: Long story short, this is something that needs to be offered by Sentry API which at the time of this question it was not. An issue was opened, but at some point abandoned. I had obfuscate less aggressively, so that Sentry logs kept making sense.